# How do I select distinct and count those selected?

Tags: sql, count, ssms, distinct

How do I select distinct and count those selected? This is my code for the Select Distinct:

```
SELECT distinct  [ClientID]
  ,[AssessmentDate]

FROM [dbo].[UserAssessrcads]
```

I would like it to end with:

```
RCADS      62
```

(or something like that)

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`

Comment: Your output does not appear to show a date.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dinamic table

```
  select count(*) from ( 
      SELECT distinct  [ClientID]
              ,[AssessmentDate]
        FROM [dbo].[UserAssessrcads] ) t
```

Comment: Isn't this just a sub select? I mean there is a specific temp table approach, which would be a bit different?

Comment: @DHN   your comment is  correct   in not a proper temp table because in not declared and create as a temp table .. but is not properly only a subselect  because  is a table  dinamically generated .. .. anyway i have slightly update my answer ..

Comment: I dont understand how this answers the original question? This is no different than just doing select count(*) from UserAssessrcads?

Comment: @ChristopherTrevor   the original question select the distinct clientID  ... but the OP need to know the number of this  rows ... my answer is a simple way for obtain this number  .. simply counting the number of  rows of the OP select ... hope this is useful

Comment: Ah ok, I'm with you now. Misread the question, thought it needed to be a count for each clientID

Answer (score 3):

The better way to do this is:

```
SELECT [ClientID],[AssessmentDate], count(1)
FROM [dbo].[UserAssessrcads]
group by [ClientID],[AssessmentDate]
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the result I asked for.

Comment: Hi @DavidJeffery, Did you want the count per 'client Id- Assessment date' combo or the number of such combos?
If former, my query gives you that. If latter, I don't understand what 'RCADS' in your sample output means.